# How to detect cycles when using shared_ptr

Tags: c++, garbage-collection, shared-ptr, reference-counting

`shared_ptr` is a reference counting smart pointer in the Boost library.

The problem with reference counting is that it cannot dispose of cycles. I am wondering how one would go about solving this in C++.

Please no suggestions like: "don't make cycles", or "use `weak_ptr`".

**Edit**

I don't like suggestions that say to just use a `weak_ptr` because obviously if you know you will create a cycle, then you wouldn't have a problem. You also cannot know you will have a cycle at compile time if you generate `shared_ptr`s at runtime.

So please, self delete answers that use `weak_ptr` in them because I specifically asked not to have those kind of answers...

Comment: Could you give a little more detail about the problem you are trying to solve. (edit the post)

Comment: You know, it sounds like you want a garbage collector. They're available for C++. One such beast is available here: http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/ but I haven't used it and can't tell you how well it works, if at all. 
But seriously, fix your design.

Comment: I don't like the Boehm conservative collector because it leaks like crazy the more your stack and heap grows. Having cycles of shared_ptr does not necessarily mean that the design needs to be "fixed". Otherwise Java and .NET would have reference counting GCs.

Comment: @Unknown "_Having cycles of shared_ptr does not necessarily mean that the design needs to be "fixed"._" What does it mean?

Comment: @curiousguy He is explaining that if someone is developing a programming language it is natural to occur cycles: the user of the programming language may create the cycle himself. For these cases having a Garbage Collector is a necessity and not a bad design. Of course there might be a lot of cases where a GC would be an overkill, however, OP clearly states that cycles are unavoidable in his project.

Comment: @VinGarcia But if you use `shared_ptr` (or any other similar lifetime control smart ptr) in this case, where there is no ownership, then it looks like the design is in error.

Comment: Uhm, you are right in the sense `shared_ptr` was designed for describing ownership. However, it is also a perfect fit for a simple reference counter GC, which when implementing a declarative language (with no cycles) would make perfect sense to use. In this second interpretation, it is natural to wonder if it could also be used when there are cycles since CPython and PHP do use a reference counting system together with a cycle detecting mechanism such as Mark & Sweep. Thus, I would ask for a pro and cons discussion before arguing it to be a bad design. (That's the reason I end up here)

Comment: Often, in your situation, you know where all pointers need to have been released and occasionally it will be ok if all pointers are still alive before that point. In that case, the thing to use is a trivial implementation of a memory arena. Cycles or not, I would always try to work around the need of a shared_ptr, but often this is simply not feasible. I hope I am not too late for my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't found a much better method than drawing large UML graphs and looking out for cycles.

To debug, I use an instance counter going to the registry, like this:

```
template <DWORD id>
class CDbgInstCount
{
public:
#ifdef _DEBUG
   CDbgInstCount()   { reghelper.Add(id, 1); }
   CDbgInstCount(CDbgInstCount const &) {  reghelper.Add(id, 1); }
   ~CDbgInstCount()  { reghelper.Add(id, -1); }
#else
#endif
};
```

I just ned to add that to the classes in question, and have a look at the registry.

(The ID, if given as e.g. 'XYZ!' will be converted to a string. Unfortunately, you can't specify a string constant as template parameter)

Comment: What is reghelper ?

Answer (score 28):

`shared_ptr` represents *ownership* relation. While `weak_ptr` represents *awareness*. Having several objects owning each other means you have problems with architecture, which is solved by changing one or more *own*'s into *aware of*'s (that is, `weak_ptr`'s).

I don't get why suggesting `weak_ptr` is considered useless.

Comment: If you could know ahead of time that there would be a single static owner, auto_ptr would be sufficient and you wouldn't need shared_ptr. I've always thought of shared_ptr as a "last one out, turn off the lights" mechanism.

Comment: Having shared_ptr to object means controlling that object's lifetime.
Having a shared_ptr where weak_ptr would be sufficient means you probabaly have object's lifetime control in more places than you could suggest.

Comment: weak pointers are a design decision, in common a restriction to use cases.

Answer (score 22):

I understand your annoyance at being glibly told to use `weak_ptr` to break cyclic references and myself I almost feel rage when I am told that cyclic references are bad programming style.

Your ask specifically how do you spot cyclic references. The truth is that in a complex project some reference cycles are indirect and difficult to spot.

The answer is that you should not make false declarations that leave you vulnerable to cyclic references. I am serious and I am criticizing a very popular practice - blindly using shared_ptr for everything.

You should be clear in your design which pointers are owners and which are observers.

For owners use `shared_ptr`.

For observers use `weak_ptr` - all of them, not just those you think may be part of a cycle.

If you follow this practice then the cyclic references will not cause any problems and you don't need to worry about them.
Of course you will have a lot of code to write to convert all these `weak_ptr`s to `shared_ptr`s when you want to use them -  Boost really isn't up to the job.

Comment: +1 for "all of them, not just those you think may be part of a cycle"

Answer (score 5):

It's fairly easy to detect cycles:

- set a count to some largish number, say 1000 (exact size depends on your application)
- start with the pionter you are interested in and follow pointers from it
- for each pointer you follow, decrement the count
- if the count drops to zero before you reach the end of the pointer chain, you have a cycle

It's not, however, very useful. And it is not generally possible to solve the cycvle problem for ref-counted pointers - that's why alternative garbage colection schemes like generation scavenging were invented.

Comment: This does not seem to be a correct answer. The answer does not "detect" cycles, instead the algorithm just says "there *may* be a cycle in the code".

Comment: "following" requires some design beyond shared_ptr

Answer (score 3):

A combination of `boost::weak_ptr` and `boost::shared_ptr` maybe? [This](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/C-Sharp/SatView-Pointer-Perfect-part-3-5/3/) article may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

See this post on [detecting cycles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261573/best-algorithm-for-detecting-cycles-in-a-directed-graph/770690) in a graph.

Answer (score 1):

The generic solution to finding a cycle can be found here:

[Best algorithm to test if a linked list has a cycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249/best-algorithm-to-test-if-a-linked-list-has-a-cycle)

This assumes that you know the structure of the objects in the list, and can follow all of the pointers contained in each object.

Comment: I would like to know how people specifically do that when using shared_ptr. It seems to me you need to add some overhead to make a directed graph out of all the shared_ptrs and keep track of their owners. I want to know the usual way to go about doing this.

Comment: Shared_ptr doesn't keep a graph, just a count of the number of outstanding valid pointers. That's why you can't traverse it to find the cycle without outside knowledge of how the pointers are used.

Comment: @ Mark, my point is that you __need__ to create a directed graph of the shared_ptrs to collect cycles.

Comment: Not neccessarilly, if you have the ability to retrieve "reflection" data for each class, you can simply start at one class, flag it as marked, and then move onto each pointer contained within the class, marking each as you go, then unmark it as you leave the recursive function. If the you ever encounter an already marked class, then you have found a loop.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably in need of a Garbage Collector technique such as [Mark and Sweep](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mark-and-sweep-garbage-collection-algorithm/). The idea of this algorithm is:

1. Keep a list with references to all memory blocks allocated.
2. At some point you start the garbage collector:

   1. It first marks all the blocks it can still access without using the reference list.
   2. It goes through the list erasing each item that could not be marked, implying it is not reachable anymore so it is not useful.

Since you are using `shared_ptr` any still existing pointers you fail to reach should be considered as members of a cycle.

#### Implementation

Below I describe a very naive example of how to implement the `sweep()` part of the algorithm, but it will `reset()` all remaining pointers on the collector.

This code stores `shared_ptr<Cycle_t>` pointers. The class `Collector` is responsible for keeping track of all the pointers and deleting them when `sweep()` is executed.

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>

class Cycle_t;
typedef std::shared_ptr<Cycle_t> Ref_t;

// struct Cycle;
struct Cycle_t {
  Ref_t cycle;

  Cycle_t() {}
  Cycle_t(Ref_t cycle) : cycle(cycle) {}
};

struct collector {
  // Note this vector will grow endlessy.
  // You should find a way to reuse old links
  std::vector<std::weak_ptr<Cycle_t>> memory;

  // Allocate a shared pointer keeping
  // a weak ref on the memory vector:
  inline Ref_t add(Ref_t ref) {
    memory.emplace_back(ref);
    return ref;
  }
  inline Ref_t add(Cycle_t value) {
    Ref_t ref = std::make_shared<Cycle_t>(value);
    return add(ref);
  }
  inline Ref_t add() {
    Ref_t ref = std::make_shared<Cycle_t>();
    return add(ref);
  }

  void sweep() {
    // Run a sweep algorithm:
    for (auto& ref : memory) {
      // If the original shared_ptr still exists:
      if (auto ptr = ref.lock()) {
        // Reset each pointer contained within it:
        ptr->cycle.reset();

        // Doing this will trigger a deallocation cascade, since
        // the pointer it used to reference will now lose its
        // last reference and be deleted by the reference counting
        // system.
        //
        // The `ptr` pointer will not be deletd on the cascade
        // because we still have at least the current reference
        // to it.
      }
      // When we leave the loop `ptr` loses its last reference
      // and should be deleted.
    }
  }
};
```

You can then use it like this:

```
Collector collector;

int main() {
  // Build your shared pointers:
  {
    // Allocate them using the collector:
    Ref_t c1 = collector.add();
    Ref_t c2 = collector.add(c1);

    // Then create the cycle:
    c1.get()->cycle = c2;

    // A normal block with no cycles:
    Ref_t c3 = collector.add();
  }

  // In another scope:
  {
    // Note: if you run sweep an you still have an existing
    // reference to one of the pointers in the collector
    // you will lose it since it will be reset().
    collector.sweep();
  }
}
```

I tested it with Valgrind and no memory leaks or "still reachable" blocks were listed, so it is probably working as expected.

Some notes on this implementation:

1. The memory vector will grow endlessly, you should use [some memory allocation technique](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/operating_system/os_memory_allocation_qa2.htm) to make sure it does not occupy all your working memory.
2. One may argue that there is no need of using `shared_ptr` (that works like a Reference Counting GC) to implement such a Garbage Collector since the Mark and Sweep algorithm would already take care of the job.
3. I did not implement the mark() function because it would complicate the example but it is possible and I will explain it below.

Finally, if you are concerned with (2), this kind of implementation is not unheard of. CPython (the main implementation of Python) does use a mixture of Reference Counting and Mark and Sweep, but mostly for [historical reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9062209/why-does-python-use-both-reference-counting-and-mark-and-sweep-for-gc).

#### Implementing the `mark()` function:

To implement the `mark()` function you will need to make some modifications:

It would be required to add a `bool marked;` attribute to `Cycle_t`, and use it to check whether the pointer is marked or not.

You will need to write the `Collector::mark()` function that would look like this:

```
void mark(Ref_t root) {
  root->marked = true;

  // For each other Ref_t stored on root:
  for (Ref_t& item : root) {
    mark(item);
  }
}
```

And then you should modify the `sweep()` function to remove the mark if the pointer is marked or else `reset()` the pointer:

```
void sweep() {
  // Run a sweep algorithm:
  for (auto& ref : memory) {
    // If it still exists:
    if (auto ptr = ref.lock()) {
      // And is marked:
      if (ptr->marked) {
        ptr->marked = false;
      } else {
        ptr->cycle.reset();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It was a lengthy explanation, but I hope it helps someone.

Comment: How to detect cycles involving pointers which are members of an object?

Answer (score 1):

If you have Cycles with shared pointers, you will have memory leak. So, if you dump memory leak objects, you can look at the types of these to find the actual cycle.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're really asking for [something like Java's garbage collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1910194/111307). [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34373460/feasibility-of-automatic-cycle-breaker-for-stdshared-ptr) talks about an "automatic cycle breaker" for `shared_ptr`.

You *can* have `shared_ptr` cycles in your program and have every object deallocate, but it's against the popular recommendation. The popular recommendation is to [break the `shared_ptr` cycle by using `weak_ptr`](https://ddanilov.me/shared-ptr-is-evil/#reference-cycles) in one of the objects that participates in the cycle.

If you insist on keeping a `shared_ptr` cycle in your program, you still can do it, but you have to *manually* break the `shared_ptr` cycle at destruction time.

This is a lot like remembering to manually call `delete` on an object, so you can see why it's not recommended.

```
struct B;

struct A {
    shared_ptr<B> b;
    void prepForShutdown() {
        b = nullptr; // unlink from b.
    }
    ~A() { puts("~A"); }
};

struct B {
    shared_ptr<A> a;
    ~B() { puts("~B"); }
};

int main() {
    shared_ptr<A> a = make_shared<A>();
    shared_ptr<B> b = make_shared<B>();
    a->b = b;
    b->a = a;

    a->prepForShutdown();  // Break the cycle
    // Without this, either dtor cannot run, because A holds a reference 
    // to b and B holds a reference to A.

    a = nullptr;
    b = nullptr;

}
```

Comment: Java does an asynchronous garbage collection, which is one option.

Comment: @SamGinrich Garbage collecting is slow, though...

Comment: ... yes, where I meant, it runs concurrent to operational functions. You also could do it synchronous, i.e. identify unused object immediately, which might be better, when there are real times requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Answer for the old question, you may try out the intrusive pointer which may help out to count how many times the resource being referred.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/intrusive_ptr.hpp>

class some_resource
{
    size_t m_counter;

public:
    some_resource(void) :
        m_counter(0)
    {
        std::cout << "Resource created" << std::endl;
    }

    ~some_resource(void)
    {
        std::cout << "Resource destroyed" << std::endl;
    }

    size_t refcnt(void)
    {
        return m_counter;
    }

    void ref(void)
    {
        m_counter++;
    }

    void unref(void)
    {
        m_counter--;
    }
};

void
intrusive_ptr_add_ref(some_resource* r)
{
    r->ref();
    std::cout << "Resource referenced: " << r->refcnt()
              << std::endl;
}

void
intrusive_ptr_release(some_resource* r)
{
    r->unref();
    std::cout << "Resource unreferenced: " << r->refcnt()
              << std::endl;
    if (r->refcnt() == 0)
        delete r;
}

int main(void)
{
    boost::intrusive_ptr<some_resource> r(new some_resource);
    boost::intrusive_ptr<some_resource> r2(r);

    std::cout << "Program exiting" << std::endl;

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Here's the result returned.

```
Resource created 
Resource referenced: 1 
Resource referenced: 2 
Program exiting 
Resource unreferenced: 1
Resource unreferenced: 0 
Resource destroyed
*** Program Exit ***
```

Answer (score 0):

How about just using Valgrind or LLVM's address santizer?

For something like:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

struct A {
shared_ptr<A> p;
    ~A() { cout << "Destructor called" << endl; }
};

int main() {
  shared_ptr<A> x(new A);
  shared_ptr<A> y(new A);
  x -> p = y;
  y -> p = x;
  return 0;
}
```

I see:

```
==12156== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==12156== Copyright (C) 2002-2022, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==12156== Using Valgrind-3.20.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==12156== Command: ./a.out
==12156==
==12156==
==12156== HEAP SUMMARY:
==12156==     in use at exit: 80 bytes in 4 blocks
==12156==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 1 frees, 72,784 bytes allocated
==12156==
==12156== 80 (16 direct, 64 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 4 of 4
==12156==    at 0x4844F2F: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/libexec/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==12156==    by 0x40121C: main (main.cpp:37)
==12156==
==12156== LEAK SUMMARY:
==12156==    definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks
==12156==    indirectly lost: 64 bytes in 3 blocks
==12156==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12156==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12156==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==12156==
==12156== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==12156== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

The `definitely lost: 16 bytes in 1 blocks` detects it.  You can get a similar output with the address sanitizer.  I agree that Valgrind / ASan will detect other stuff too and will not pin-point the cause, but it will detect the circular dependency.

Answer (score -1):

I know you said "no weak_ptr" but why not? Having your head with a weak_ptr to tail, and tail with a weak_ptr to head will prevent the cycle.