# How does a "finalizer guardian" work in java?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, finalizer

How does a "finalizer guardian" [Effective Java , page 30] work ?

Have you used them? Did it solve any specific problem ?

Comment: Haven't used it.  Maybe because I don't writing finalizers.

Answer (score 20):

It solves the problem of the sub-class forgetting to call the `finalize` method of the super-class. This pattern works by attaching an extra instance with overridden `finalize` to your super-class. This way, if the super-class goes out of scope, the attached instance would also go out of scope, which would trigger the execution of its `finalize`, which would in turn call the `finalize` of the enclosing class.

Here is a short snippet that showcases the guardian pattern in action:

```
public class Parent {

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
        doIt();
        System.gc();
        Thread.sleep(5000); //  5 sec sleep
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private final Object guardian = new Object() {
        @Override protected void finalize() {
            doFinalize();
        }
    };

    private void doFinalize() {
        System.out.println("Finalize of class Parent");
    }

    public static void doIt() {
        Child c = new Child();
        System.out.println(c);
    }

}

class Child extends Parent {

    // Note, Child class does not call super.finalize() but the resources held by the
    // parent class will still get cleaned up, thanks to the guardian pattern
    @Override protected void finalize() {
        System.out.println("Finalize of class Child");
    }

}
```

Comment: But when the times come for the Parent class to be GC'ed , the parent class will not be able to be GC'ed since the anonymous class holds a reference to Parent class and the Parent class also holds a refrence to the anonymous class through the instance field link.  So because of this circular reference how will the Parent and the anonymous class be eligible for garbage collection?

Comment: @Geek: Java has a pretty awesome GC which isn't tripped by circular references. More [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194)

Comment: Should the `Parent.finalize()` call `Parent.doFinalize()`? Doesn't that result in `doFinalize()` getting called twice if the `Child` does call `super.finalize()` or if an instance of `Parent` is finalized?

Comment: @MichaelAnderson: +1; you are indeed correct in mentioning that the public class Parent shouldn't have a `finalize` method overridden. Edited.

Comment: @SanjayT.Sharma, Regarding "*Note, Child class does not call super.finalize()*", **yet** in the very first place, why would that even happen? Isn't it part of the contract for all child class finalizers to call `super` finalize ?

Comment: @Pacerier: Nope, it's not part of the contract (just another overridden method) and the sole reason for having the guardian pattern. It does not work like constructor chaining.