# Does the Java garbage collector clean stack memory?

Tags: java

Is the garbage collector in Java used for clearing unused objects from heap memory only, or does it actually lend a hand in cleaning the stack memory too?

Comment: You can't put stuff on the stack which could be cleared by the garbage collector.

Comment: @svens actually not true - the JIT will allocate objects on the stack if it can, but obviously GC on a stack doesn't make any sense - how would that work?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The only things that lives on the stack are references and instances of primitive types. Both of those are ignored by the garbage collector.

Answer (score 8):

There is no garbage that lives on the stack.

Answer (score 4):

Garbage collection only happens on heap for Objects that are no longer reference from any [GC roots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/how-does-java-garbage-collection-work-with-circular-references/18350729#18350729).

Stack is where your local variables (like primitives and object references) live. There is no concept of GC here. Think of stack data structure. If a local variable is in scope (of a particular thread's stack frame) it is pushed to this stack frame and when it is out of the scope it is poped out of stack frame.

Answer (score 0):

Its objects which don't have a strong reference from a thread stack which can be cleaned up.