# Why don't listeners in Android create memory leaks?

Tags: android, android-layout

Below the prototype code I read about for creating customer listeners for Android Widgets.
My question is, if the parent view registers itself as the "FooListener" and the parent maintains a reference to the FooWidget, why isn't a memory leak created, since the Widget has a reference to its parent and the parent presumably has a reference to this widget?

Does the containing activity somehow shutdown all of its constituents when it goes out of scope even if there's a circular reference between two of its children?

```
public class FooWidget extends View implements OnClickListener {

    private FooEventListener listener;
    public Button fooButton;
    public FooWidget(Context context) {
        super(context);
        fooButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.myFooButton);
        fooButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     }
    public abstract class FooEventListener {
        public abstract void onFoo(View v);
    }
    public void registerListener(FooEventListener listener) {
        this.listener=listener;
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (listener!=null) {
            listener.onFoo(this);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/garbage-collection-in-java-and-circular-references

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, if the parent registers itself as a FooListener, that does not automatically mean that it maintains a reference to the FooWidget. Even if it did, circular references do not create a memory leak. If both objects are unreachable from active code, then they will be gc'ed even if they reference one another.