# Eligibility of an Object for GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

If Object A has reference of object B and object B has reference of Object A and they don't have any other live reference then are they eligible for GC?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/garbage-collection-in-java-and-circular-references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Garbage collection of objects in Java can occur if the objects are not *reachable*. It isn't affected by circular references.

One definition of reachability is provided by the package documentation for [java.lang.ref](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html):

> Going from strongest to weakest, the different levels of reachability reflect the life cycle of an object. They are operationally defined as follows:
>
> - An object is strongly reachable if it can be reached by some thread without traversing any reference objects. A newly-created object is strongly reachable by the thread that created it.
>     An object is softly reachable if it is not strongly reachable but can be reached by traversing a soft reference.
> - An object is weakly reachable if it is neither strongly nor softly reachable but can be reached by traversing a weak reference. When the weak references to a weakly-reachable object are cleared, the object becomes eligible for finalization.
> - An object is phantom reachable if it is neither strongly, softly, nor weakly reachable, it has been finalized, and some phantom reference refers to it.
> - Finally, an object is unreachable, and therefore eligible for reclamation, when it is not reachable in any of the above ways.

Answer (score 0):

Java's GC considers objects "garbage" if they aren't reachable through a chain starting at a garbage collection root, so these objects will be collected. Even though objects may point to each other to form a cycle, they're still garbage if they're cut off from the root.