# Java GC on an object-"chain" loose in memory

Tags: java, garbage-collection

During runtime, object `object1` is referring to object `object2`. 
However, `object1` has no reference to it.

In this case, would `object1`, and thus `object2` be collected by GC?

If yes -- `object2` has a reference to it and is being "automatically" 
removed from the memory in this case.

If no -- than that would be because `object2` has a reference to it 
(from `object1`) and that's why it isn't collected. 
But then `object1` is loose, and it should be collected.

How does the GC work on these? Does it collect `object1` first cause it's "loose" in memory, then, in the next round, it collects `object2` cause it is loose now that it isn't referenced. 
Or it collects `object1` and `object2` both when it's on collecting `object1`?

Another case that might be is: `object1` is running a process. 
So, GC doesn't touch it, and `object2`, being references from `object2`, remains 
in memory as well. 
But this wouldn't hold-- from what i know, GC doesn't look up whether the object 
has CPU time assigned to it(?), it just goes by the references and whenever 
there's no reference to it, removes the object from the heap.

How does GC work on these two objects-- `object1` & `object2` in this case?

//========================================

EDIT:

This is a Q on the specifics of GC. Anyone can look up "GC collects objects that aren't referenced."

TIA.

Comment: Note that there may be other _reachable_ references to `object2`. So `object1` may be collected, but `object2` will be left alone.

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing Object and references, as long as any Object in heap has live reference to it it will not be GCed

Answer (score 0):

[How does Java Garbage Collection work with Circular References?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/garbage-collection-in-java-and-circular-references?rq=1) gives the answer -- both `object1` and `object2` are collected since "they aren't reachable from a GC root". It also implies that they both are collected at once-- not `object1` first and then `object2` which is eventually loose.