# Java Garbage Collector Class A -> Class B -> Class C-> Class B And Cyclic Reference

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a question related to Garbage Collection in Java

Let us thought of a situation

There are three classes **Class A,Class B,Class C**

- Now **A has B**
- **B has C**

Now say A=null; (I assign null to A)

Will A be eligible for Garbage Collection ?

If yes, What will happen to C then ?

Comment: It would help if you'd show us actual code rather than just describing it... If you're asking whether it handled cyclical references, the answer is "yes" .

Comment: What is a 'query related garbage collector'?

Comment: @isnot2bad I would imagine a 'question related to garbage collection'.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Garbage Collection in Java and Circular References](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/garbage-collection-in-java-and-circular-references)

Comment: I would have shown the code, but I have just assumed a situation. And considering the duplication the question is slight difference. Classes A,B and C can be of different type. In http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25285095/java-garbage-collector-class-a-class-b-class-c-class-b-and-cyclic-refere Node has a same type of object inside it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is yes.

The garbage collector searches the object graph and can identify when object sub-trees have been disconnected and sweep the entire sub-tree; regardless of the fact a cycle exists in the subtree.

If the instance of the C class gets collected; the GC will execute the finalizer and then destroy the object.

Answer (score 0):

It is not about what is within which object. The GC will just swipe through all objects and check if it is *reachable*. `finalize()` method will be executed only when the GC determines that an Object is unreachable.

```
public class TryThreads {
B b = new B();

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("TryThreads finalizing..");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TryThreads t = new TryThreads();
    t = null;
    System.gc();
    System.runFinalization();

}
```

}

```
class B {
String s = new String("hello");

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("B finalizing");
}
```

}

O/P :

```
B finalizing
TryThreads finalizing..
```

Now, if `b` of the `TryThread` instance t had a Strong reference.

public class TryThreads {
    B b = new B();

```
@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("TryThreads finalizing..");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TryThreads t = new TryThreads();
    B b = t.b; // keeping a reference of b within t. only t will be collected, not b.
    t = null;
    System.gc();
    System.runFinalization();

}
```

}

```
class B {
String s = new String("hello");

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("B finalizing");
}
```

}

O/P :

```
TryThreads finalizing..
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but that's a very complex answer to the simple question. And I'm not even sure you really answered the questions, which are: "Will A be eligible for garbage collection?" and "What happens to C?"

Comment: @isnot2bad - thanks for telling what you felt was wrong with my answer.. I've indeed answered the OP's question. In the second case I've also shown what happens if a reference to the inner variable leaks. :(