# javascript circular reference - breaking the cycle

Tags: javascript, circular-reference

For example, I have this code:

```
var objectA = {};
var objectB = {};

objectA.pointer = objectB;
objectB.pointer = objectA;

objectA = null;
objectB = null;
```

I assume that after last two statements, there is no reference to objects originally assigned to objectA and objectB variables. But according to the technical literature, the reference for those objects still exists. Why ? Does **objectA.pointer** reference or **objectB.pointer** reference still exists even the objectA and objectB are set to null ?

Comment: `objectA = null;` only sets the value of the *variable* `objectA` to `null`. It does not change the value of the *property* `objectB.pointer`. `objectB.pointer` still refers to an object. Variables / properties are just containers for values. An assignments "copies" the value and now two containers contain the "same" value (each has their own copy). Replacing the value in one of the containers doesn't magically replace the value in another container.

Comment: Setting `objectA` to `null` does not change `objectB.pointer`

Comment: @FelixKling: How could **objectB.pointer** refer to the object if objectB is set to null ?

Comment: Again, variables and properties are *containers*. When you do `objectB.pointer = objectA;` then you are copying the *content* from one container to another. In other words `objectB.pointer` does **not** refer to the *container* `objectA` but to the *value* that it has/had. Later when you do `objectA = null;` you are changing the *content* of *container* `objectA`. That has no impact on `objectB.pointer`. Here is a simpler example: `var foo = 42; var bar = foo; foo = 0;`. `bar` has still the value `42` even though I set `foo` to `0`. Changing the value of `foo` has no impact on `bar`.

Comment: @FelixKling I understand how copying between primitive and reference values works. What I am talking about is this: In my example there are two objects. At beginning they have one reference - first object has reference in objectA and second object has reference in objectB. Then second reference is created for these objects. First object has second reference in objectB.pointer and second object has second reference in objectA.pointer. So how we could decrease references for both objects to zero ? I assumed that this is achieved by setting both objectA and objectB to null.

Comment: *"So how we could decrease references for both objects to zero ?"* You can't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does `objectA.pointer` reference or `objectB.pointer` reference still exists even the `objectA` and `objectB` are set to `null` ?

Yes.

Maybe some ASCII art helps. After performing

```
var objectA = {};
var objectB = {};
```

the environment contains two variables (`objectA` and `objectA`) that hold references to two objects (denoted as `ref:XXX`):

```
                          +--------------+
+-------+---------+  +--->|  Object#123  |
|objectA|ref:123 *+--+    +--------------+
+-------+---------+                       
|objectB|ref:456 *+--+    +--------------+
+-------+---------+  +--->|  Object#456  |
                          +--------------+
```

After adding properties to the objets,

```
objectA.pointer = objectB;
objectB.pointer = objectA;
```

both objects have a `pointer` property each contain a reference to the other object:

```
                         +-----------------+      
                         |   Object#123    |      
                    +--->+-------+---------+<----+
+-------+---------+ |    |pointer|ref:456 *+---+ |
|objectA|ref:123 *+-+    +-------+---------+   | |
+-------+---------+                            | |
|objectB|ref:456 *+-+    +-----------------+   | |
+-------+---------+ |    |   Object#456    |   | |
                    +--->+-------+---------+<--+ |
                         |pointer|ref:123 *+-----+
                         +-------+---------+
```

As you can se see, there is no relation between a `pointer` property and the `objectA` and `objectB` variables. `objectA.pointer` doesn't refer to the variable `objectB`, it got a copy of its value (`ref:456`), a reference to the object.

After setting both variables to `null`,

```
objectA = null;
objectB = null;
```

the environment looks like this:

```
                         +-----------------+      
                         |   Object#123    |      
                         +-------+---------+<----+
+-------+---------+      |pointer|ref:456 *+---+ |
|objectA|  null   |      +-------+---------+   | |
+-------+---------+                            | |
|objectB|  null   |      +-----------------+   | |
+-------+---------+      |   Object#456    |   | |
                         +-------+---------+<--+ |
                         |pointer|ref:123 *+-----+
                         +-------+---------+
```

The `pointer` properties still hold the references to the other object. Replacing the values of `objectA` and `objectB` didn't change that.

Comment: Oh beautiful ascii art  ! Thanks, this is explained very well. I clearly understand the problem now. I was blind :) Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about this, `JS` is a managed language and has an built in `Garbage Collector`, that will take care of this case. Read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)

What you're describing is solved in various techniques. You can read in this question [How does Java Garbage Collection work with Circular References?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/how-does-java-garbage-collection-work-with-circular-references) about its implementation in `Java`.