# Should I unsubscribe when using rxbinding?

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin, rx-binding

There is how I use RxBinding with Kotlin:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    reset_password_text_view.clicks().subscribe { presenter.showConfirmSecretQuestionBeforeResetPassword() }
    password_edit_text.textChanges().skip(1).subscribe { presenter.onPasswordChanged(it.toString()) }
    password_edit_text.editorActionEvents().subscribe { presenter.done(password_edit_text.text.toString()) }
}
```

`Observable.subscribe(action)` returns `Subscription`. Should I keep it as reference and unsubscribe `onPause()` or `onDestroy()`?

Like this:

```
private lateinit var resetPasswordClicksSubs: Subscription

override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    resetPasswordClicksSubs = reset_password_text_view.clicks().subscribe { presenter.showConfirmSecretQuestionBeforeResetPassword() }
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    resetPasswordClicksSubs.unsubscribe()
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've made a small test setup to find it out. It's not an Android app but it simulates the class relationships. Here's what it looks like:

```
class Context
class View(val context: Context) {
    lateinit var listener: () -> Unit
    fun onClick() = listener.invoke()
}

fun View.clicks() = Observable.fromEmitter<String>({ emitter ->
    listener = { emitter.onNext("Click") }
}, Emitter.BackpressureMode.DROP)


var ref: PhantomReference<Context>? = null

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var c: Context? = Context()
    var view: View? = View(c!!)

    view!!.clicks().subscribe(::println)
    view.onClick()
    view = null

    val queue = ReferenceQueue<Context>()
    ref = PhantomReference(c, queue)
    c = null

    val t = thread {
        while (queue.remove(1000) == null) System.gc()
    }
    t.join()

    println("Collected")
}
```

In this snippet I instantiate a `View` that holds a reference to a `Context`. the view has a callback for click events that I wrap in an `Observable`. I trigger the callback once, then I null out all references to the `View` and the `Context` and only keep a [`PhantomReference`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html). Then, on a separate thread I wait until the `Context` instance is released. As you can see, I'm never unsubscribing from the `Observable`.

If you run the code, it will print

> Click
>
> Collected

and then terminate proving that the reference to the `Context` was indeed released.

---

### What this means for you

As you can see, an `Observable` will not prevent referenced objects from being collected if the only references it has to it are circular. You can read more about circular references in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/how-does-java-garbage-collection-work-with-circular-references).

However this isn't always the case. Depending on the operators that you use in the observable chain, the reference **can** get leaked, e.g. by a scheduler or if you merge it with an infinite observable, like [`interval()`](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/interval.html). Explictly unsubscribing from an observable is always a good idea and you can reduce the necessary boilerplate by using something like [RxLifecycle](https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle).

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation! In my case `.editorActionEvents()` still emitting events even after disposing `View`. I will try to use RxLifecycle to unsubscribe with `onDestroy`.

Answer (score 16):

I think that Jake Wharton (the creator of the library) gave the [best answer](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/issues/282):

> Treat a subscribed RxView.clicks() (or any Observable from this
>   library for that matter) like you would the View reference itself. If
>   you pass it (or subscribe to it) somewhere outside the lifetime of the
>   View, you've just leaked your entire activity.
>
> So if you're just subscribing inside your ViewHolder there's no need
>   to unsubscribe just like there'd be no need to unregister a click
>   listener were you doing it manually.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you should [unsubscribe when using RxBinding](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/view/RxView.kt).

Here's one way... (in java, could be tweaked for kotlin?)

## Collect

Within your Activity or Fragment, add disposables to a CompositeDisposable that you'll dispose at onDestroy().

```
CompositeDisposable mCompD; // collector

Disposable d = RxView.clicks(mButton).subscribe(new Consumer...);

addToDisposables(mCompD, d); // add to collector

public static void addToDisposables(CompositeDisposable compDisp, Disposable d) {
    if (compDisp == null) {
        compDisp = new CompositeDisposable();
    }

    compDisp.add(d);
}
```

## Dispose

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    mCompD.dispose();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Take great care if CompositeDisposable exists but is disposed, when adding another Disposable it will call disposable.dispose() immediately. That's why we should recreate the CompositeDisposable even if comDisp.isDisposed()

Answer (score 4):

Yep, if you look in the [doc](https://github.com/JakeWharton/RxBinding/blob/master/rxbinding-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/jakewharton/rxbinding2/view/RxView.kt), it explicitely says:

> - *Warning:* The created observable keeps a strong reference to `view`. Unsubscribe to free this reference.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. If the activity is destroyed and nothing is keeping a reference to it, the observable will be collected, too. The question is, does using RxBinding create any references to the activity that wouldn't be created if you just used the listener? My guess is no, unless you use some operators that run on special schedulers.

Comment: If you look at any view constructor, it takes a reference to the context. Therefore any unsubscribed binding will prevent your activity to be garbage collected.

Comment: Not if the only reference is a loop. Which is exactly the same with passing an anonymous inner class.

Comment: This observable never completes and hold your reference until you unsubscribe.