# Garbage collection and Memory leak in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have read that in Java, GC (Garbage Collection) will clean up objects that are not referenced in the Heap memory.

I am not sure how to test or not sure if, after line 3, the variables person, room (in the voidTest function) can be called as having no reference.

Does anyone know how to test or could explain further for me?

Thank you!

```
class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        voidTest();
        // is Gc clean room and person variable in void Test ?
    }

    public static void voidTest(){
        Person person = new Person();
        Room room = new Room();

        room.person = person;
        person.room = room;
    }
}


class Room{
    public int id;
    public Person person;
}

class Person{
    public String name;
    public Room roon;
}
```

Comment: In a small program like this, the GC won't have time to run and the program will just exit (which removes all remaining objects).

Comment: @markspace Thank you for your response. I simulated a small section within a large program to better understand GC. Do you have any additional information for me?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking. The `person` object can't be called, so it will be removed by the GC eventually.  However this isn't rational code, so I don't think you've correctly copied the code you are asking about.

Comment: Object Room still holds a reference to Person, and vice versa, Object Person still holds a reference to Room
What do you about think this ? @markspace

Comment: No, the GC can detect circular references like this, and both will be removed.  It is not a problem.  (Solved by the JVM many, many years ago.)

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/how-does-java-garbage-collection-work-with-circular-references

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: It turns out that this question is actually about circular references, which I blanked on because obviously circular references are removed (which is only obvious if you've been programming in Java for 15 years).  Here's a link to the SO question that the OP found useful:
[How does Java Garbage Collection work with Circular References?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910194/how-does-java-garbage-collection-work-with-circular-references)

Finalizers aren't a great idea and they are [being removed](https://openjdk.org/jeps/421) from the language.  But they are still available, so that allows you to do some cheap and easy GC testing.  Calling `System.gc()` manually allows you to see the result of a garbage collection.

```
public class GCTesting {
   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      test();
      System.gc();
   }
   private static void test() {
      new GCTesting();
   }
   @Override
   protected void finalize() {
      System.out.println( "Bye!" );
   }
}
```

Since `finalize()` is being removed I updated my program to give a quick example how to do this with a `PhantomReference`.  In my testing, I had to call `remove()` instead of `poll()` because it seems to take a bit of time for the referent to be enqueued, `poll()` would always return `null` immediately after a call to `System.gc()`.  In more normal code, I'd assume `poll()` would be the better choice.  I'm calling `remove(1000)` just because I want the test to end after a brief wait.  Also, saving the `PhantomRefence` is important, otherwise it will also be garbage collected (and never enqueued).

```
public class GCTesting {
   public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
      finalizers.add( new Finalizer( new GCTesting(), collected ) );
      System.gc();
      for( Reference<?> f; (f = collected.remove(1000)) != null; )
         System.out.println( "collected " + f );
   }
   static ReferenceQueue<GCTesting> collected = new ReferenceQueue<>();
   static ArrayList<Finalizer> finalizers = new ArrayList<>();
   static class Finalizer extends PhantomReference<GCTesting> {
      public Finalizer( GCTesting gct, ReferenceQueue<GCTesting> q ) {
         super( gct, q );
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that calling System.gc() is just a suggestion to the JVM. There is no guarantee it will cause an actual GC every time. Also it should not be used to try to manage the memory manually.

Comment: But for all practical purposes this test runs fine.

Comment: I don't remember it not executing a GC but it is a fair warning to others. Also it should not be used lightly.

Comment: Even simpler with a `Cleaner`: `public class GCTesting { public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
Semaphore collected = new Semaphore(0);
Cleaner.create().register(new GCTesting(), () -> {
  System.out.println("Collected");
  collected.release();
});
System.gc();
collected.acquire();
} }`