# Test single linked list for cycle

Tags: java, algorithm

Is there a way to check if a single-linked list contains cycles for linear time without copying and modifying the list?

I thought we could try to sort this list topologically. If cannot there is somr cycle... But it seems it's not gonna work.

Comment: Use classical solutions with fast and slow iterator. It can even tell you where the loop starts

Comment: You could do a dfs and if you reach a visited node then it's either a cross edge or a back edge. To distinguish back edges, use "colors" to determine whether you are currently processing a node (recursing on its children) or have completed its processing recursed back up to it). Then all back edges are cycles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect a loop in a linked list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663115/how-to-detect-a-loop-in-a-linked-list)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in constant space without altering the array.

The method is known as [Floyd's cycle-finding algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd.27s_Tortoise_and_Hare). It is based on the idea of going through the list with two pointers moving at different speeds. Eventually, if and only if the list contains a cycle, the pointers will meet. Also, the algorithm finds the point where the loop starts. Check the provided link for more details.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comment, you can use fast and slow iterator solution.

**Key insight:**

> The key insight in the algorithm is that, for any integers i ≥ μ and k
>   ≥ 0, x(i) = x(i + kλ), where λ is the length of the loop to be found
>   and μ is the index of the first element of the cycle. In particular, i
>   = kλ ≥ μ, if and only if x(i) = x(2i). Thus, the algorithm only needs to check for repeated values of this special form, one twice as far
>   from the start of the sequence as the other, to find a period ν of a
>   repetition that is a multiple of λ. Once ν is found, the algorithm
>   retraces the sequence from its start to find the first repeated value
>   xμ in the sequence, using the fact that λ divides ν and therefore that
>   x(μ) = x(μ + v). Finally, once the value of μ is known it is trivial
>   to find the length λ of the shortest repeating cycle, by searching for
>   the first position μ + λ for which x(μ + λ) = x(μ).

Reference Link :
[Floyd's Tortoise and Hare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_detection#Floyd.27s_Tortoise_and_Hare)