# SinglyLinkedList cycle detection

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures

I am doing some HankerRank challenges to practice algorithms/data structures, and I am having trouble.  The problem is to detect loops in a singly linked list.  This is an obvious use of Floyd's cycle finding algorithm, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I also checked my answer to others, and it seems to be doing the same thing.  If anyone can help me out I would appreciate it.

```
 // Complete the hasCycle function below.

    /*
     * For your reference:
     *
     * SinglyLinkedListNode {
     *     int data;
     *     SinglyLinkedListNode next;
     * }
     *
     */
    static boolean hasCycle(SinglyLinkedListNode head) {

        // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2663115/how-to-detect-a-loop-in-a-linked-list

        SinglyLinkedListNode start = head;

        //there is no list
        if(start == null) { 
            return false;
        }

        // have both start at beginning
        SinglyLinkedListNode slow = head;
        SinglyLinkedListNode fast = head;

        while(true) {

            slow = slow.next; //hop one ahead

            //fast.next may be null, so fast.next.next will cause a null pointer exception
            if(fast.next != null) {
                fast = fast.next.next; //hop two ahead
            } else {
                return false;
            }

            //They are the same node so 'slow' must have caught up
            if(slow == fast) {
                return true;
            }

            //We reached the end of the list with no next, so there must not be a loop
            if(slow == null || fast == null) {
                return false;
            }

        }

    }
```

Thanks for any advice.

****EDIT**** Sorry for being unclear about what the problem is.  When running it on HackerRank, the following input: 1 1 3 1 2 3, fails.  My code returns that there is no cycle, when the correct answer is that there is a cycle.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: "I can't seem to get it to work" What is the actual problem? Runtime exception? Infinite loop? Incorrect results? Questions seeking debugging help must include a specific problem or error, else they are off-topic.

Comment: In what case does it fail?

Comment: Is there a reason you moved `slow == fast` to happen before `slow == null || fast == null`?

Comment: @Michael Sorry, I updated it.  And there is no particular reason.  I just thought about slow == fast before the other check.  I didn't think it mattered which one was first.

Comment: Are you sure you construct the list correctly?

Comment: @user58697 Yes, this is a problem off of HankerRank.

Comment: In case I was not clear: The loop detection part is correct. It means that the problem is elsewhere, in the part of code you did not show. Most likely, it is in the list construction.

Comment: @user58697 I'll have to look more closely.  There is code that constructs the list for you, so I doubt there could be a problem there.

Comment: @LoganPhillips when you initialize `slow` and `fast`, fast always needs to be 2 nodes ahead of `slow`. So, `fast = head.next.next`.