# How to identify if a given single linked list is a loop?

Tags: c, data-structures

I was asked in an interview to find if the single linked list has a loop. I have searched this SO and found few answers **Interview question: How to detect a loop in a linked list?** and I knew about those answers before but somehow I answered it different which I had in mind from my discussion with friends long time back, but I wasn't sure if the answer is correct. If try it myself it works as expected. Somehow the interviewer is not happy. Can someone clarify what is wrong in this ?

```
struct node {
int flag;
struct node *next;
}
```

My idea here is not to use two pointers and hop variantly but to use single pointer and traverse each node e.g:

```
node =  node->next;
```

Only this I would do is set the flag variable to 1 when ever I traverse the node and check each time e.g

```
if (node->flag)
{ 
  return TRUE; // implies list is a loop
}
else{
   node->flag = 1;
}
```

Other than efficiency, what is wrong in this approach ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34249/best-algorithm-to-test-if-a-linked-list-has-a-cycle and the questions linked to there for other approaches.

Comment: @delnan : Yes , I went through this question also. I mostly covered all the related questions in SO. However, my question is to understand what is wrong in this approach.

Comment: These kind of questions only shows if you've read these kind of questions before and are familiar with the answer. I would never use it as a measure on how skilled a developer are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an extra integer variable `flag` and say if the `sizeof(int)` in your machine is 4 bytes and say you have 100,000 nodes in the linked-list, then you will end up using 400,000 bytes more. That will be approximately 390M/.38G

To reset the `flag` for all the nodes in the linked-list, even though it is O(n), you'll have to traverse all the 100,000 nodes. Its an overhead.

Now, if you compare your `flag` based solution with the 2-variable solution, then it is almost the same computational time but 2-variable solution is considered very memory efficient as it does not use 390M of memory to identify the loop!

Comment: After all linked list is used to store the data which can be of some size, I don't disagree but that cannot be the reason I think so. Also, i'll be setting flag as and when I traverse the node how is it overhead.

Comment: Efficiency I agree , that's what I mentioned.

Comment: @dicaprio There is nothing wrong with the `flag` approach. It will work! There is no doubt about that. But compare to the other solution(s), this may not be very efficient. And, the approaches are compared based on efficiency - memory, computation and many other factors! :)

Comment: @dicaprio Are you not finding my answer reasonable?!

Comment: As I said , I don't disagree with your comments; perfectly reasonable with regards to efficiency, which I already told the interviewer, his question was not specific.

Comment: @dicaprio Interviews can sometimes be insane! And, interviewers can sometimes be weird!!

Answer (score 3):

You need additional data (`flag`) to store for each list item. So your approach needs O(N) additional memory, while approach with two pointers needs only O(1) memory.

So you approach is not memory efficient.

Comment: Good answer, but the example in the question also requires the list structure to be modified which is probably more relevant.

Comment: @JeremyP, interview questions of this type is aimed to show knowledge of algorithms, data structures, complexity, etc. So I think, more relevant is memory efficiency, regardless how this memory is used.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is even more efficient but relies on the fact that you may modify the list representation. When asked the same question I gave the same solution but the interviewer told me I am not allowed to modify the list in any way.

Comment: So the approach is not wrong then, if you already know this approach earlier then its not something i found myself :). Is there a algorithm or somebody already named it ?

Comment: Honestly saying I just invented it on the spot :)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is not wrong, rather instead of using two pointers, it makes use of just one pointer. But giving this answer for the interview question you over looking one basic premise.

You are generally not supposed to alter the data structure of the problem which you are given until it is absolutely necessary to do so. Consider it from this point of view.

What if it's not a linked list but an application  that the company has developed and they need you to find out if a particular thing stands true for that application or not. In this case they don't expect you to change the application code(as that is impractical unless unavoidable) but would like you to work around with what you have got.

Because of this your interviewer was not happy with the answer. You can always give this answer in addition to the other answer, but not as your answer of choice.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps `Hare and Turtle` would work.  The `Turtle` interates through the list normally, one item at a time, while the `Hare` goes twice as fast, two items at a time.  If the `Hare` passes the `Turtle`, there is a loop.

**Edit**: I see this suggestion is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34255/318716), and that it has already been rejected by the OP, in his comments.