# Checking if two list have the same elements in it, in the same order, but with other starting points in Python

Tags: python

I need to write a function where I need to check if two lists with elements like these

```
(['E', 'A', None, 'D', 'B', None, None, 'C'], ['B', None, None, 'C', 'E', 'A', None, 'D'])
```

have the same elements, in the same order, but with other starting points.

So if you search `'E'` in the second list, and take that as starting point, you get:

```
(['E', 'A', None, 'D', 'B', None, None, 'C'], ['E', 'A', None, 'D', 'B', None, None, 'C'])
```

These two are the same, so they have to return `True`.

If they are not the same, it needs to return `False`.

I'm sorry for the duplicate, I'm not a native english speake and didn't knew how to express it

Comment: Hi!  Welcome to the site!  How far have you got?  What is it you've got stuck on?  Can you include some code in your answer?

Comment: Also, check [how to check whether two lists are circularly identical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924836/how-to-check-whether-two-lists-are-circularly-identical) and [fastest way to prove linked list is circular in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20353835/fastest-way-to-prove-linked-list-is-circular-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can reliably serialise the lists to strings, then you can easily do this using a cheap and fast substring check.

A [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26924836/how-to-check-whether-two-lists-are-circularly-identical) was asked recently, and here is this basic idea stolen from there:

```
l1 = ['E', 'A', None, 'D', 'B', None, None, 'C']
l2 = ['B', None, None, 'C', 'E', 'A', None, 'D']

if len(l1) == len(l2) and set(l1) == set(l2):    
    sep = ' '  # choose something that won't be in the data
    str_2l1 = sep.join(repr(x) for x in l1 + l1)
    str_l2 = sep.join(repr(x) for x in l2)
    return str_l2 in str_2l1
else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage [difflib.get_matching_block](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.SequenceMatcher.get_matching_blocks) to easily solve the problem.

**NOte** There can be algorithm more efficient than this, but you didn't ask for the most efficient.

### Implementation

```
def is_same(l1, l2):
    import difflib
    sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, *l)
    a, b, s = sm.get_matching_blocks()[0]
    if s:
        return l1 == l2[b:] + l2[:b2]
    return false
```

### Alternate Implementation

```
def is_same(l1, l2):
    import difflib
    sm = difflib.SequenceMatcher(None, l[0], l[1]*2)
    a, b, s = sm.get_matching_blocks()[0]
    return s == len(l1)
```

### Example

```
>>> l = (['E', 'A', None, 'D', 'B', None, None, 'C'], ['B', None, None, 'C', 'E', 'A', None, 'D'])
>>> is_same(*l)
True
```

Answer (score -3):

This really depends on the types of lists you're using. For example, the problem is immensely simplified if you know that at least one element, for example `'A'`, appears exactly once in any list you have. If this is the case, you could do something like:

```
list1 = [your first list]
list2 = [your second list]

for i in range(len(list1)):
    if list1[i] == 'A':
        split1A, split1B = list1[i:], list1[:i]
        check1 = split1A + split1B

#Repeat for list2

if check1 == check2: return True
else: return False
```

Really, the complexity of the answer depends on the nature of the lists.